# Run external python file with Mininet

Tags: python, mininet, pox

I try to write a defense system by using mininet + pox.

I have l3_edited file to calculate entropy. I understand when a host attacked.

I have my myTopo.py file that create a topo with Mininet.

Now my question:

I want to change hosts' ips when l3_edited detect an attack. Where should I do it?

I believe I should write program and run it in mininet. (not like custom topo but run it after create mininet, in command line). If it's true, how can I get hosts' objest? If I can get it, I can change their IPs.

Or should I do it on my myTopo.py ??? Then, how can I run my defense code, when I detect an attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone looking for answer...

You can use your custom topology file to do other task. Multithread solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
h1.cmd('ifconfig h1 192.168.1.0')
```

or xterm

Comment: I need more complex than this. I need to run external python code.